# Show Iframe after Image has Faded Out

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I am using this code where a user clicks on the image and then the youtube video is loaded and autoplayed. Everything works apart from the fact that the video instantly appears at the bottom of the image, once the image is clicked by the user.

I need to figure out some code so that the image fade outs completely and then the video is shown. What I tried in my code with `delay` doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
<div id="vidocr" onclick="thevid=document.getElementById(\'thevideo\');thevid.style.display=\'block\';document.getElementById(\'iframe\').src=document.getElementById(\'iframe\').src.replace(\'autoplay=0\',\'autoplay=1\');">
  <img class="vidovi" title="" src="https://www.wpfreeware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/placeholder-images.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display:none;">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppEqly6GFsA?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(\'#vidocr\').click(function(){
    jQuery(\'#vidocr\').fadeOut(500);
    jQuery(\'#thevideo\').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rdmwtcbx/1/

```js
$('#vidocr').click(function(){
  $('#vidocr').fadeOut(500, function(){
    $('#thevideo')
      .fadeIn('slow')
      .find('iframe#iframe')
      .attr('src', $('iframe#iframe').attr('src').replace('autoplay=0', 'autoplay=1'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vidocr">
  <img class="vidovi" title="" src="https://www.wpfreeware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/placeholder-images.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="thevideo" style="display:none;">
  <iframe id="iframe" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ppEqly6GFsA?rel=0&vq=hd720&color=white&autoplay=0&wmode=transparent&theme=light&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

`jQuery` `fadeOut` is having callback function, once `fadeOut` completes `fadeIn` will start for the video & auto play will happen.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks but I need  the code to replace \'autoplay=0\' with \'autoplay=1\ - like in my example. Your code appends ?autoplay=1. I can't do that because my youtube url already has other parameters following the ?.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai In your code, where is the **autoplay=0** is present and what parameters your **YouTube url** is having.

Comment: I have updated my code with the full Youtube address

Comment: I tried the new code but it gives the original problem as I described. Please try this at Jfiddle. Maybe the "replace" part is what causing the issue?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Check the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rdmwtcbx/2/ . It's working fine